# have to be able to swim / were to be able to swim

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, irrealis-mood

> You **have to be able** to swim to attend the pool.

This sentence is grammatical.

> If all **were to be able** to swim, all could attend the pool.

This sentence is not. But how to explain it from the grammar standpoint?

P.S.

Could it be that the latter sentense is grammatical but not equal in meaning to

> If all **were able** to swim, all could attend the pool.

Comment: By explaining that "have to be + attributive" goes together and "be + attributive" is a completely different construction? That in the second sentence you use the verb _be_ twice for no reason, so there is one too many? By making it easier and start with "John is able to swim" vs "John is to be able to swim", where the _extra_ "to" and the _extra "be" are more obvious, maybe?

Comment: The last example is great, thanks, @oerkelens! But "he is to be able" is a combination [found at Google Books](http://books.google.ru/books?id=QW8p6AiXVMcC&lpg=PA153&dq=%22he%20is%20to%20be%20able%20to%22&hl=ru&pg=PA153#v=onepage&q=%22he%20is%20to%20be%20able%20to%22&f=false).

Comment: Your link refers to a Russian book. But the _phrase_ he is to be able to ..." can be correct. The _sentence_ is not. If you make a complicated sentence, those words may appear in that order: If the child is to be able to learn to be careful not to be left alone, you have to teach him from an early age. There are many many _bes_ that I could add to that sentence, but it won't make it clearer :P

Comment: @oerkelens I've just thought that "*John is to be able to swim by September 1*" looks grammatical: John should learn to swim by Sept. 1.

Comment: Yes, and if you add stuff to your original #2 sentence, it becomes grammatical as well. Hence my example with two _sentences_. If you keep them like that, it seems clear that one is right and one is wrong :)

Comment: @oerkelens: But isn't "John is to be able to swim" grammatical? "John should learn to swim, with no deadline provided".

Comment: @CopperKettle Yes, that's perfectly grammatical.

Comment: What do you mean by  *attend the pool*? It's not clear. We could  say *go to the pool* if we mean *enter the pool grounds*. We could  say *use* if we mean *get in the pool (and swim)*.  We could also  say *go swimming (in the pool)*. *Attend* is not idiomatic for any of these. We don't *attend the pool* like we *attend the conference*. *Attend the pool* could mean something like *service/clean  the pool*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this sentence:

**If all party-goers were to be sober before being given their car keys, why was K. allowed to drive off without being given a sobriety test?**

The construction "all were to be {adjective}" expresses a requirement that each and every member of the set "all" had to satisfy.

Put an "if" in front of it, "if all were to be sober", and the statement means:

If each and every party-goer *had to be* sober (in order to obtain his car-keys, ...)

The result that does NOT flow from that if-clause is: *each and every party-goer could obtain his car keys.

The *requirement|stricture* that drivers be sober does not mean that all drivers will satisfy the requirement.

P.S.

Were to be {adjective}  <>  "were {adjective}"

Were to be  = were supposed to be, were required to be.

**Those papers were to be on my desk by noon!**  (It's well past noon, and those papers are not yet on his desk.)

P.P.S. Those papers are to be on my desk by noon tomorrow!
(requirement, quasi-imperative).

Comment: I see! Thank you, @TRomano! It was [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206427/a-question-about-the-use-of-the-subjunctive-mood/206428) question that got me wondering.

Comment: I don't think this is the same use of *to* here! In your example, it means 'should have been', I don't think it does in the OP's example!

Comment: I have heard passive constructions such as "If all were to be given the vaccine, we could eradicate the disease* but never "If all were to be able...". I did not know what to make of the OP's second sentence; it made no clear sense to me as a native speaker.